# Mac OSX app: how to get alert 'App X would like to use your current location' at first launch?

Tags: xcode, macos, geolocation, location, cllocationmanager

When I first ran my OSX app with a call to location services to determine the user location, I get an alert asking the user if he allows the app to use his location.

I don't manage to get the alert again !! What I tried:

- fully delete the "derived data" folder (where my app is)
- make a clean
- went to OSX preferences => "Security and confidentiality" => unchecked the checkbox relative to my app in order to forbid the use of the location => doesn't display the alert again anyway !
- delete the plist file in user/my_name/library/preferences

Impossible to get this alert again !

I want to display this alert again because I want to check different things at first startup (namely the behaviour of my app if the user wait a long time before accepting the use of his location)

Thanks for your answer !

Nota: I saw many posts on this forum but only relative to iOS, not to Mac OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't make a comment so I'll post it as answer :-/

This worked for me though it's not the best way I could imagine: https://superuser.com/questions/429344/remove-application-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10-7

Comment: Thanks, I did what is explained in this post. I removed the key relative to my app from the dictionary but now I have some other bugs... 1) I have got a discrepency between the clients.plist file and what is displayed in my preferences: I no longer have my app in the plist (I removed it) but it is still displayed in the preferences 2) Even if I clicked on the alert to allow the location services, the key is not back to my clients.plist 3) My app is no longer able to determine my location even if [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]  always returns YES => always get didFailWithError

Comment: 4) If I allow or forbid the location services for my app in the user preferences, the result is the same: the location is not determined. Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Actually, the behaviour of all these stuffs became completely cahotic... 1) Sometimes I get the startup alert, sometimes not 2) the list of apps using location services sometimes displays all my apps using location services, sometimes is empty... 3) In all cases, the clients.plist is never modified ! Any idea ?

Comment: I've edited the file, saved it and then tried to restart locationd which wasn't running for some reason. I then opened the preference pane which started locationd and also the entry (iStumbler). At least after confirming the application again the clients.plist file was rewritten to the binary format. Hope this helps, otherwise I have no idea (maybe you've got a caching issue or something else went wrong). All in all I can't reproduce your problems though did you read the comments there? Seems he ran into the same problem which was classified as known bug (I'm running 10.7.5).

Comment: ... Maybe this is related to the sandbox? iStumbler isn't sandboxed your application probably is (assuming you're gonna publish your app in the MAS).

Comment: Can you explain how you "tried to restart locationd"? In terminal? If yes,in which folder is this executable ? You say "I then opened the preference pane which started locationd"=>didn't you start it just before (via Terminal or other), why do you restart it? "and also the entry (iStumbler)": what does it mean? what is iStumbler used for? "clients.plist file was rewritten to the binary format": how do you know what is the format? I am not an expert in sandboxing...my app is indeed for the Mac App Store;what should I do to solve a sandboxing issue? What is the link with iStumbler?Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `killall` usually restarts the application (at least if you kill Finder, Dock, etc. which it doesn't with `kill <pid>`). iStumbler is a 3rd party app, the only one which shows up in the list for me so I tested it with that one. I've got an error when trying to execute `killall locationd`. `ps aux | grep location` showed me that it wasn't running. It seems to start up when it is requested (like for instance in the preference pane) and shuts down if not used. Just `cat clients.plist` and if there  is any non-ASCII character it's likely binary (at least it will differ from what you've edited).

Comment: And the reason for restarting the service is just to make sure that my settings are getting applied. And just for your information, I'm a web developer with some interests so I just basically know what a sandbox is ;-)

Comment: Hi ! I FIXED THE PROBLEM thanks to the help of the guy who wrote the answer. See the entire discussion here : http://superuser.com/questions/429344/remove-application-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10-7 Thanks for your help, I really appreciated !!